# Citrix Receiver Resolution issue

Tags: resolution, virtual-desktop, citrix, vdi, citrix-receiver

I have a problem with Citrix, when open a VDI , this appears in a box does not appear with the full resolution , after 10/15 min returns to normal , this happens only when Citrix opens and connects to VDI .

I reinstalled Citrix Receiver, graphic drivers, restarted VDI, but does not works.

The local Mahcine have W10x64 and the VDI OS is a Server 2008 R2 x64

PD: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Those are usually pre-defined installed machines, you should see if there are GPOs running on the start-up, who checks the resolution of the screen, perhaps they are running too late or the machine is busy with other processes.

Or try the Web version and check if the problem persist.